# Returning data from the View to the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After the user has edited data in my View, how to I get the data back to my Controller so I can update my database?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Cv(int Id)
    {
        Cv CvBlog = new Cv();
        CvPerson = db.Cv.Find(Id);

        return View(CvBlog);
    }
```

View Example

In this case I'd like to return the new value for Name

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Show the method your posting back to.

Comment: create a method with string name (id of your input box) as parameter and post back to that method

Comment: I'm posting to the controller in my example? Or do I have to create another ActionResult?

Comment: posting to wat controller? and use name instead of id. It is the standard. id would work but sometimes it messes up things.

Comment: The html you have shown will not post back anything. You need to have a `name` attribute. And learn to use the strongly typed helpers to generate the correct html for your model properties `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` Then you need a separate method decorated with `[HttpPost]` to post back to. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add the id's of the HTML inputs to the paramter list of the return function like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Cv(int id, string name)
{
  //TODO: update Cv by whatever means you determine
  return View("Index");
}
```

A better option would be to create a ViewModel that would capture the values (still based on the id's of the HTML inputs).  This way you can also do some simple field/property level checking on them.

View Model:

```
public class CvEditViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [MaxLength(50)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Cv(CvEditViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
  {
    //TODO: update Cv by whatever means you determine
    return View("Index");
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of OP, suggest adding the view code `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

instead of value attribute use the name attribute in view as follows.
`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="@Model.Name">`

to get the value in controller use `string name=Request["Name"]` Request["Name"] will have the value which the user has entered

Answer (score 0):

in view just set name property

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
```

in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cv(int id, string name)
{
  //TODO: update Cv by whatever means you determine
  return View("Index");
}
```